# Como aparecer uma view dentro da ViewController depois de apertar um botão?

Tags: ios, swift, view

Estou começando a programar em **Swift** e gostaria de saber como faço para ocultar e mostrar uma *view* que está inserida na `ViewController` após acionar um botão.

No app, o usuário irá passar alguns dados e clicar no botão, ao clicar no botão alguns cálculos são feitos. Gostaria que os resultados fossem mostrados nessa *view* que irá aparecer.

Answer (score 1):

Para ocultar/mostrar uma view em tempo de execução você usa a propriedade `hidden` de UIView. Exemplo:

```
  @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    myView.hidden = true
  }
```

Nesse exemplo, `myView` é a referência para a view que deve aparecer quando o botão for clicado.
Uma view escondida não recebe eventos e também esconde suas subviews.

**UPDATE**

versão em Swift 3 da resposta do @rafael-leao:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Deu Certo, Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo, também sou iniciante, porém eu faria com uma abordagem diferente, da sugerida pelo Rafael.

Eu usaria o `Storeboard`, para construir o flow das views, sendo assim quando se tem um botão que exibe uma nova view, basta você clicar sobre o botão em questão, com a tecla `CTRL` pressionada e arrastar para a nova View, assim sempre que este botão for pressionado ele levará para a nova View.

Caso precise que alguma ação além desta seja realizada, como por exemplo preencher algum dado ou consultar algum banco de dados, você pode simplesmente adicionar uma ação do tipo `Touch Up Inside`, para isso basta clicar no botão com a tecla `CTRL` e arrastar o botão para o código sobre a função que irá tratar o evento ou criar nova função especifica.